# Using variables and elements together in jQuery multiple selectors

Tags: jquery-selectors, multiple-select

So...I'm trying to shrink down some JS code a bit, and I have things like...

```
$('#element-A'+idx).hide();
$('#element-R'+idx).hide();
$('#element-Z'+idx).hide();
```

Is there a reliable way I can smash these down into one statement without taking a performance hit?

I tried:

```
$('#element-A'+idx,'#element-R'+idx,'#element-Z'+idx).hide();
```

...but that just gave me an error, which actually is what I thought would happen.

I also tried:

```
$(['#element-A'+idx,'#element-R'+idx,'#element-Z'+idx]).hide();
```

...but I also got an error from that.

The only other possibility I can think of is:

```
$('#element-A'+idx).add('#element-R'+idx).add('#element-Z'+idx).hide();
```

But doesn't that create a new object, in effect taking up more memory??

What should I do?? Or am I better off just leaving them as separate commands?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a single selector string:

```
$('#element-A'+idx + ', #element-R'+idx + ', #element-Z'+idx).hide();
```

Or, better yet, add a common class to all of the elements, and just use that instead.

Comment: The comma inside the quotes fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your commas need to be inside the quotes:

```
$('#element-A'+idx,'#element-R'+idx,'#element-Z'+idx).hide();
```

should be

```
$('#element-A' + idx + ', #element-R' + idx + ', #element-Z' + idx).hide();
```